# Как отобразить значение main в Языке C?

Tags: c, функции, main

Вот `int main` может возвращать целое значение, а куда? Где посмотреть, как увидеть?
Гулг со своей задачей не справился, либо я не справился со своим вопросом, теперь я здесь...
Если билдить в кодблоксе, то тот автоматически отображает значение return. Мне бы тоже как-то это сделать.

Comment: Возвращает системе. Это errorlevel в windows, $? в юниксах и т.д.

Comment: Код выхода передаётся родительскому процессу, а родительский процесс может прочитать его с помощью системного вызова wait или waitpid (в юниксах)

Comment: Вы хотите увидеть значение не в Code blocks, а в другой среде разработки? Если это так, то вы всегда неправильно использовали return, он нужен не для этого в main. Прочитайте статью: http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/printf

Comment: В *nix его можно увидеть, набрав `echo $?` непосредственно после выполнения программы